# Length of array doesn't seen in Intellisense

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Now i send message array as a query string to another page.but when i catch the next page we have a arr.Length know ( normally it shows the intellisense) but in this case it doesn't show.

here is msg_arr pass to the another page

```
 private void check(string keyword , params Array[] msg_arr)
    {
        switch (keyword.ToUpper())
        {
            case  "SETTELG":
                Response.Redirect("../SMSFunction/SeenSMS.ascx?value=1&arr" + msg_arr);

                break;
```

Below code is the next page i wanted to catch that passed value & array(msg_arr).but length doen't work

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string Moose = Request.QueryString[1];
        }

        if (msg_arr != null)
        {
            if ((msg_arr.Length == 3) && (msg_arr[1].ToLower() == "slett"))

            {

            }


        }
    }
```

here is the second code screenshot,you can see Length not shown 
[image: here is the second code screenshot,you can see Length not shown]

Comment: Where does `msg_arr` come from in the second piece of code?

Comment: Where's definition of `msg_arr` in Page_Load?

Comment: interesting how it isnt redlined in the initial if statement though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a few things wrong here.

```
private void check(string keyword , params Array[] msg_arr)
```

Is this function *really* being passed an array of `Array`s? I'd have thought `string[]` or `object[]` to be a more *likely* type to be passed.

```
Response.Redirect("../SMSFunction/SeenSMS.ascx?value=1&arr" + msg_arr);
```

That's going to call `ToString()` on `msg_arr`, which, it being an array, will produce a result like this:

```
"../SMSFunction/SeenSMS.ascx?value=1&arrSystem.Array[]"
```

`Array` doesn't override `ToString()`, so you get the one from [`Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) which outputs the fully qualified name of the type - which I assume isn't what you want.

Finally, we reach your second piece of code, but you've not even shown us any code which attempts to set the new `msg_arr` variable. But it's not going to be able to get the original value of `msg_arr`, since you've not passed that across yet.

---

You need to decide how you want to pack your array into the query string. If, say, `msg_arr` should have been an array of readable strings (`params string[] msg_arr` in the `check` definition), then you might try something like:

```
Response.Redirect("../SMSFunction/SeenSMS.ascx?value=1&arr=" + string.Join("|",msg_arr));
```

where `|` is a character that shouldn't appear in the strings being passed. ([`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx))

You can then reconstruct it back into an array with something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] msg_arr = Request.QueryString["arr"].Split('|');
    /* rest of method */
```

([`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a))

Of course, there may be a concern now if the length of strings (or the number of them) is too large, it may not be appropriate to pass them via a query string at all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass whole collection in query string. Only thing you can do is pass an element of collection. i.e. array cannot be passed but array[0].toString() can be. Please do it in a simple way through session variable. Store array in Session variable in Page1.aspx and retrieve on Page2.aspx. Sample code is as follows

Page1.aspx

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
      int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
      Session["Array"] = array; Response.Redirect("About.aspx"); 
    }
```

Page2.aspx

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
      int[] array; 
      if (Session["Array"] != null) 
      { 
         array = (int[])Session["Array"]; 
         if (array.Length == 3) 
         { 
            /////implementaion 
         } 
      } 
    }
```